# STL to store the numbers in sorted order

Tags: c++, stl

which is the ideal STL container to use in C++ for a sorted insert for the integers which could contain duplicates.

Comment: How do you want to use the container? What are the operations to be done with the container? How frequent (relatively) is each one of those operations? (BTW: The question is half baked and almost impossible to answer without extra information, which makes me wonder why the up votes)

Comment: used to store the integer sorted container using the indexes like 2nd highest e.t.c

Comment: How many insertions? How frequent compared to lookups? Is the container initialized and then only lookups performed? Are they interleaved? You are still not answering the key questions.

Comment: lookups and insertions are interleaved .. insertions of the order 10^6 and same for the lookups

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you possibly a std::multiset 
It will store duplicates but when you iterate over the container you'll get them in sorted order

Answer (score 0):

The two obvious choices are a heap/`priority_queue` or a `multiset`. The heap will only let you access the largest element at any point while the `multiset` will store the items (with duplicates) in sorted order, allowing you to iterate over them.

With more information about your specific problem a more refined answer could be provided.

Comment: can we access the elements in the multiset using the index like the arrays ?

Comment: @titan No you cannot access like array using index.

Comment: @titan if you want random access at the elements of you container then use `std::map/std::multimap`

Answer (score 0):

`std::multiset` is probably the expected answer.

If the domain is relatively small (especially compared to the number of incidences), then counting sort can be used to good effect however.  You would use `std::vector<int>` with the size of the domain.  Then the value becomes the index, and the count becomes the number of incidences.

Answer (score 0):

If the lookups and insertions are interleave with that magnitude, I would rather suggest a simple vector and sort it when the lookup period starts.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the following:

1. `std::multiset` found at the `<set>` header
2. `std::priority_queue` found at the `<queue>` header

You can also store the data into a `std::vector/std::deque/std::list` and then sort them using the `std::sort` function, which is found at the `<algorithm>` header.